# How can we combine predictors from two different linear models into one?

Tags: r, statistics

I was trying to automate a final step model building. I would like to combine predictors from two separate models into one final model. I played around with `update.formula()` but realized  I can update an old lmfit$call to a new one, e.g `update.formula(lmfit$call,lmfitnew$call)`. here i need to cherry pick variables from both models and run the final one

```
lmfit1 <- lm(y~ x1+x2+x3, data = modelready)
best.ngc_fit <- stepAIC(lmfit1, direction="backward")
best.ngc_fit$call

lm(formula = y~ x2+x3, data = modelready)

lmfit2 <- lm(y ~ a+b+c+d+f, data=fcstmodel)
best.fcst_fit <- stepAIC(lmfit2, direction ="backward")
best.fcst_fit$call

lm(formula = y~ a+c+d+f, data = fcstmodel)
```

This is what I would like to have in my final model

```
best.full_fit <- lm(y~x2+x3+a+c+d+f, data = fullmodel)
```

I can do it manually without a problem, but I would like to automate it in order to make the whole process less tedious.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Why not merge the data and try creating a holistic model first? Setting x1,x2,x3 = 0 where a,b,c,d,f > 0, and the converse. ie, use a data.frame containing colums x1,x2,x3,x4,a,b,c,d,f where the variables are 0 filled as appropriate?

Comment: Brandon, thank you for your input, this model is originally written in SAS. The way model is structured is combining two best models. The predictors from the first best model is from macroeconomic variables related price index( e.g house price index), predictors from second best model is related to labor index such a unemployment rate and so forth.  I don't have freedom to change the basic structure of data flow into the model. If I do that, I cannot sell this to upper management. I work for a leading BANK in US, lot of stuffs we do doesn't make sense to us and so do to public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more advanced manipulation of fomulas you can use *Formula* package.

```
formula(as.Formula(terms(lm1),formula(Formula(terms(lm2)), lhs=0)), collapse=TRUE)

y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (X5 + X7)
```

Answer (score 5):

If this is just a matter of extracting the components of each model and combine them into a new design matrix, then the following should work, irrespective of the fact you used `stepAIC`:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), replicate(7, rnorm(100)))
lm1 <- lm(y ~ X1+X2+X3, dfrm)
lm2 <- lm(y ~ X5+X7, dfrm)
lm1.fm <- attr(terms(lm1), "term.labels")
lm2.fm <- attr(terms(lm2), "term.labels")
lm3.fm <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(c(lm1.fm, lm2.fm), collapse= "+")))
lm3 <- lm(lm3.fm, dfrm)
```

To fix the ideas, here we have

```
> names(dfrm)
[1] "y"  "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6" "X7"
> lm3.fm
y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X5 + X7
```

See `help(terms.object)` to get more information on what it returns. With your example, you'll need to replace `lm1` with `best.ngc_fit` and  `lm2` with `best.fcst_fit`.

Comment: Christophe, thank you sir. That worked very well and helped me learning by digging deep into object created by lm(). Visited your website and realized you have been a great teacher giving R crash classes. Please let me know if you have any online classes. Thank you once again.

Comment: Glad to hear this helps you getting deep into R objects. I'd recommend to look at R online help to check what is returned by a function as well as issuing a simple `str(your.object)` as R prompt. Thanks for your comment on my courses (most recent slides are [here](http://www.aliquote.org/cours/2012_biomed/), but this is in French; you will probably find a lot of other good/better tutorials by googling a little bit :-)